# Get the column name from column A and then save the value of that column in a new column C

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this: (it is based on image analysis and uses 3 different algorithms with their confidence level to guess what the image was)

```
p1    p1_conf   p2    p2_conf   p3       p3_conf
dog   0.45      cat   0.32      book     0.05
dog   0.01      book  0.9       table    0.5
...
```

The eventual goal is to find the best prediction (the one with the highest confidence level): i.e. dog for the 1st row and book for the 2nd row.

I have used the following code to find the maximum confidence level and the name of the column with the maximum confidence level:

```
df['max_conf'] = df[['p1_conf', 'p2_conf', 'p3_conf']].max(axis=1)
df['max_col'] = df[['p1_conf', 'p2_conf', 'p3_conf']].idxmax(axis=1)
df['pred_algorithm'] = df['max_col'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
```

now my dataframe looks something like this:

```
p1    p1_conf   p2    p2_conf   p3       p3_conf   max_conf   pred_algorithm
dog   0.45      cat   0.32      book     0.05      0.45       p1
dog   0.01      book  0.9       table    0.5       0.9        p2
...
```

Now, I need to find the best prediction for each row using the pred_algorithm column.

I tried this:

```
df['best_prediction'] = df[df['pred_algorithm']]
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1691, placement implies 1
```

How can I make this new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to select values from a column using another column values with [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['best_prediction'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['pred_algorithm'])
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
p1  p1_conf p2   p2_conf p3   p3_conf max_conf pred_algorithm best_prediction
0   dog     0.45 cat     0.32 book    0.05     0.45 p1        dog
1   dog     0.01 book    0.90 table   0.50     0.90 p2        book
```